# Setting clustering column in BigQuery python api

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a clustered table in BigQuery.

When I test it in the UI, it works perfectly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project_id_xyz.temp.clustering`
PARTITION BY date
CLUSTER BY cluster_col AS
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() as date, 1 as cluster_col
```

However when I try the same via google-bigquery==1.9.0 in python (3.7.1), the table is created and partitioned but not clustered. As seen in the "details" tab in the UI.

Here is the snippet I use to create the table.

```
dataset = client.dataset("temp")
table = dataset.table("clustering_test")
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
job_config.destination = table
job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"

time_partitioning = TimePartitioning()
time_partitioning.field = "date"
job_config.time_partitioning = time_partitioning
job_config.clustering_fields = ["cluster_col"]

sql = """
    SELECT CURRENT_DATE() as date, 1 as cluster_col
"""
query_job = client.query(
    sql,
    location='US',
    job_config=job_config)

query_job.result()
```

Code seems very straightforward and also doesn't throw any exceptions.

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't need the entire query (as you wrote in the UI) in your sql String? Normally, in Java, I have to specify all performed actions as well as the project/dataset/table.

Comment: Why don't you just run the same query using the client API?

Comment: it's easier to change the job config programmatically via job_config rather then trying to parse and changing the SQL code directly. That's why their api offers two way of doing it I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your python code and I can confirm it's working as expected with the cluster settings.

The solution for your problem using Python 3.6.7 is to create a clean version and run your code again

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such object like Clustering() in the package. Also as per documentation clustering fields are defined as a list under job_config.clustering_fields directly if I understand it correctly. https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig

Comment: Tamir, thanks for checking! That's very helpful. At least I know that the code is correct but something wrong with my setup. Out of interest, what python version are you using?

Comment: Thank you, I've now created a clean python installation and virtualenv and it works now as well. Thanks a lot for confirming that the code worked for you, it helped to debug into the right direction.

Comment: @Dimitri Also important to vote on the answer. Vote up answers that are helpful.... You can check about what to do when someone answers your question - stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers