# how to create a table using the following python bigquery api?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, python-3.6

Hello I cloned the following repository:

https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python

I was reading the documentation about creating a table as follows:

```
schema = [
    {'name': 'foo', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'nullable'},
    {'name': 'bar', 'type': 'FLOAT', 'mode': 'nullable'}
]
created = client.create_table('dataset', 'my_table', schema)
```

I tried to execute the same in my console as follows:

```
>>> schema = [
...     {'name': 'foo', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'nullable'},
...     {'name': 'bar', 'type': 'FLOAT', 'mode': 'nullable'}
... ]
>>> created = client.create_table('data_set_course', 'my_table_testing', schema)
```

I only got 'False' and when I check the visual interface there is no table.

```
>>> print(created)
False
>>>
```

I dont have any idea about the issue, I really frustrated since I just what to create one table, so I really would like to appreciate the support to overcome this task.

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55031720/setting-clustering-column-in-bigquery-python-api/55037927#55037927 it has good python script to reuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this code and it works for me:

```
from bigquery import get_client

# JSON key provided by Google
json_key = 'key.json'

client = get_client(json_key_file=json_key, readonly=False)

schema = [
    {'name': 'foo', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'nullable'},
    {'name': 'bar', 'type': 'FLOAT', 'mode': 'nullable'}
]
created = client.create_table(dataset='yourDataset', table='tableToCreate', schema=schema)
```

You need to check 2 things:

1. `readonly` parameter in the `get_client` method is set to `False`. Otherwise BigQuery access is read-only.
2. The service account or user provided in the `key.json` file has been granted with the [permissions to create a BigQuery table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control). At least it must have the `roles/bigquery.dataEditor` role granted. To do it run the following command:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT_ID] --member "serviceAccount:[NAME]@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
```

Anyway I recommend you to use the official [Python Client for Google BigQuery](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/index.html), you will have better documentation and functionality. As well as a huge amount of code examples in the [BigQuery official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/).

Comment: Thanks I am testing this api, it seems to work, thanks a lot for the support

Comment: after the past issue now I cant execute an insert I hope you could please soporte me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55067816/why-the-following-bigquery-insertion-is-failing I really appreciate the support