# why the following Bigquery insertion is failing?

Tags: google-bigquery, python-3.6

Hello I am trying to insert one row into a table, I succesfully created the table as follows:

```
schema = [{'name': 'foo', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'nullable'},{'name': 'bar', 'type': 'FLOAT', 'mode': 'nullable'}]
created = client.create_table(dataset='api_data_set_course_33', table='insert_test_333', schema=schema)

print('Creation Result ',created)
```

However when I push the row I got False,

```
rows =  [{'id': 'NzAzYmRiY', 'one': 'uno', 'two': 'dos'}]
inserted = client.push_rows('api_data_set_course_33','insert_test_333', rows, 'id')

print('Insertion Result ',inserted)
```

So I don't have idea what is wrong, I really would like to appreciate support to overcome this task
This is the API that I am testing:

https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python

This is my complete code:

```
schema = [{'name': 'foo', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'nullable'},{'name': 'bar', 'type': 'FLOAT', 'mode': 'nullable'}]
created = client.create_table(dataset='api_data_set_course_33', table='insert_test_333', schema=schema)

print('Creation Result ',created)

rows =  [{'id': 'NzAzYmRiY', 'one': 'uno', 'two': 'dos'}]
inserted = client.push_rows('api_data_set_course_33','insert_test_333', rows, 'id')

print('Insertion Result ',inserted)
```

Output:

```
Creation Result  True
Insertion Result  False
```

After feedback I tried:

```
>>> client = get_client(project_id, service_account=service_account,private_key_file=key, readonly=False)
>>> schema = [{'name': 'foo', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'nullable'},{'name': 'bar', 'type': 'FLOAT', 'mode': 'nullable'}]
>>> rows =  [{'id': 'NzAzYmRiY', 'foo': 'uno', 'bar': 'dos'}]
>>> inserted = client.push_rows('api_data_set_course_33','insert_test_333', rows, 'id')
>>> print(inserted)
False
```

and also:

```
>>> rows =  [{'id': 'NzAzYmRiY', 'foo': 'uno', 'bar': 45}]
>>> inserted = client.push_rows('api_data_set_course_33','insert_test_333', rows, 'id')
>>> print(inserted)
False
```

However I only got false

Comment: I recommend using the official google lib for that: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

Comment: If you can get the jobid you can use it to know what's wrong. Typically the schema doesn't match the value type. You will need to find more details to dive deeper into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your row field names don't match your schema field names. Try this instead:

```
rows =  [{'id': 'NzAzYmRiY', 'foo': 'uno', 'bar': 'dos'}]
```

Comment: I also tried with this however I got false, I updated the question with the output I hope, you could please help me to find the issue